# RecyclerView scrolls only on specific view touch

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, scroll

I wonder how I can achieve such behaviour of the `RecyclerView`, that I could scroll the list only when I click and drag only specific view within the `ViewHolder`?

I've disabled horizontal scroll by creating my own LinearLayoutManager:

```
class MyOwnLayoutManager : LinearLayoutManager {

constructor(context: Context?) : super(context)
constructor(context: Context?, orientation: Int, reverseLayout: Boolean) : super(context, orientation, reverseLayout)
constructor(context: Context?, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyleAttr: Int, defStyleRes: Int) : super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes)

private var isScrollEnabled = false

fun setScrollEnabled(isEnabled: Boolean) {
    isScrollEnabled = isEnabled
}

override fun canScrollVertically(): Boolean {
    return isScrollEnabled && super.canScrollVertically()
}

override fun canScrollHorizontally(): Boolean {
    return isScrollEnabled && super.canScrollHorizontally()
}
}
```

Then, I try to change the `isScrollEnabled` by setting the touch listener to the item's header:

```
 item_header.setOnTouchListener { v, event ->
            val isScrolling = event.action == ACTION_MOVE
            onHeaderIsDragging.invoke(isScrolling)
            false
        }
```

Callback in the fragment that changes adapters' layout manager var:

```
private val onHeaderIsDragging: ((Boolean) -> Unit) = {
    recyclerViewLayoutManager.setScrollEnabled(it)
}
```

By this implementation, I get `MOTION_CANCEL` after a couple of `MOTION_MOVE` events in the `onTouchListener` and `RecyclerView` is not scrollable after `MOTION_MOVE` events.